# how to create and use a new Build configuration in Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8, angular-devkit

In my **Angular.json** file. I have

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": true,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "progress": true,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

This is executed when i run `ng build --prod`

How can I create a new configuration e.g. dev ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have added an environment configuration to angular.json you can build it by using the --configuration option. In your case `ng build --configuration=development`.

Comment: Thanks that was what i was looking for, is there any abbrevation like production has `--prod`

Comment: If this is all you're looking for just add a line to your "scripts" in the package.json so you could for instance just say `npm (or yarn) boom` and it would run `"scripts": {
    "boom": "ng build --c=development"}`